# Typescript type declarations not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror, gatsby

Working on a gatsby side project where I'm also using Typescript. I never used Typescript before so I'm expecting some sort of PHP type declaration behavior, but not sure, if that's how it works. I've done quite a lot of work and happily carried on (thinking how good I'm with Typescript), when just realized that some of my imported interfaces were undefined and never got any error because of it. So I tried to break my code by using wrong types but Typescript seems to be ignoring all the declarations.
Here is an example:
I got this interface (draggable.ts):

```
export interface Draggable {
   x: number,
   y: number
}
```

Exported by this guy (index.ts)

```
import Draggable from './draggable';
import Resizable from './resizable';
import Stageable from './stageable';
import Page from './page';
import ToolState from './states/tool-state';
import CommonAction from './states/action';
import ToolItem from './tool';

export default {
   Draggable,
   Resizable,
   Stageable,
   ToolState,
   Page,
   CommonAction,
   ToolItem
}
```

Which is then imported as follows in the component

```
import Interfaces from '../interfaces';
```

And used in the following method's type hinting:

```
 reposition: (event: MouseEvent, diffPos: Interfaces.Draggable) => {
     const position = {
         x: event.screenX - diffPos.x,
         y: event.screenY - diffPos.y
     }

    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BAR_POSITION', payload: { position }})
}
```

Now if I try to call that method with wrong argument type, the code will run with no problem:

```
<div 
  className="bg-gray-600 toolbar" 
  style={{top: barPosition.y + 'px', left: barPosition.x + 'px', width: barWidth}}
  onDragStart={dragStart}
  onDrag={e => reposition(e, 'blaa')}
  onDragEnd={e => reposition(e, diffPos)}
  draggable={true}
>
```

Even if I try something like

```
onDrag={e => reposition(e, {x: 'blaa', y: 'blablaaa'})}
```

doesn't make any difference.
Probably I'm having some misunderstanding how Typescript works.
Thanks.

Comment: When you say the code runs with no problem, do you mean TypeScript does not detect any errors (i.e. in your code editor)?

Comment: Exactly. Also at the beginning when I was writing some simple Typescript learning code examples, I was getting type errors in the browser's console as well, now that's not happening. The function just runs with the wrong type.

Comment: What environment are you using to code? (e.g. VS Code, some online editor, etc) And how is your TypeScript being transpiled to JS currently? (using the tsc command, or some bundler like webpack?)

Comment: I'm working vs code at the moment, the typescript configuration is from Gatsby out of the box at project creation. It seems that I had huge misunderstandings on what Typescript actually does. Just wondering how to run the typescript code in my code editor/terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript does not throw any errors during your javascript runtime. But it should show you errors inside your working environment(IDE), if typescript server is properly working.

I think you should at least read [this document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html) provided by Typescript before you start Typescript coding, it explains it's primary rules including below..

> Roughly speaking, once TypeScript’s compiler is done with checking your code, it erases the types to produce the resulting “compiled” code. This means that once your code is compiled, the resulting plain JS code has no type information.
> This also means that TypeScript never changes the behavior of your program based on the types it inferred. The bottom line is that while you might see type errors during compilation, the type system itself has no bearing on how your program works when it runs.

Take a look at the example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwFDLIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANwHICeZltDeAvnnguiADO2SMIxYy48MgC8uYmQDkACwgAbNekUAaFkoDu6KGoAmi5F0Z8Bg9GogA6TQHMAFKLBSwASkZA), even in the typescript playground you can see that even if it shows errors inside typescript code, it still can be run and get no errors during runtime.

Typescript code should be compiled/transpiled into javascript code for running, and depending on the compile/transpiling environment it may ignore some typescript errors. Which explains why your code was still running without errors.

> Exactly. Also at the beginning when I was writing some simple Typescript learning code examples, I was getting type errors in the browser's console as well, now that's not happening. The function just runs with the wrong type

also, it looks like the "Type Error" you mentioned is [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError), which is Javascript object and this is not thrown by Typescript.

I think you'll have to check your coding environment(IDE maybe?), which should be showing typescript errors found by running typescript server.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, yeah it seems that I got it completely wrong, what Typescript actually does. The documentation is giving more details on Typescript code concepts, rather than how to actually run things. Even in the Gatsby's documentation they point you to how to set it up, but no mentioning about how to run it (or maybe my understanding of the concept is poor). So how can I run that Typescript server? Do I need to set up Node and Express for it? Do I need to run it on individual files, or is it possible to run the type checking on the whole project?

Comment: you might not have globally installed typescript..?
check out this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_installing-the-typescript-compiler) for vs code and see if it works for you

Comment: Thank you, that sort of helped. This whole thing is much more problematic then I thought, it keeps complaining about my jsx usage, (error TS17004: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.) even if I configured the jsx value in the compileOptions tsconfig param. It also generates a bunch of js file copies of my tsx interface files every time I run tsx.  I start to understand why everyone is trying to avoid Typescript. It's a nice tool to use in order to have bug free code, but it requires too much time and effort to set it up and configure it(at least with frameworks like react).

Comment: Also, probably that one single Hello World tsx file example with one line of console log used in every tutorial and the documentation is not the best way to give a smooth start. Thank you for you help, really appreciate it. I'll try to play around with it a bit more, if won't get it working today, I will just remove it and use simple js.

Comment: not sure how gatsby sets up the project since I haven't tried it, but most frameworks supporting typescript provides great boilerplate. Since you are very new to the typescript, it might look a little bit too complicated to set up & use, but I think it is worth because it adds great readability and stability to your project code. JS alone is flexible but also fragile I think. Good luck!

Comment: Just an update, in case someone with the same struggle will stumble upon this question. I watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJDVKeh7RJI . The guy uses react. He's getting the type error straight in the browser at re-compile without running anything else. That's the sort of behavior I was expecting. Unfortunately this other guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf8eqNrcZDw confirms that Gatsby does not have this ability. Which is weird, because the React documentation highly recommends to use Gatsby/Next Js frameworks.